# ToolBar AppCompat & Action Bar backStack

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-library, android-toolbar, android-appcompat

I currently have an issue with the AppCompat Toolbar.

If I set the Theme to NoActionBar, no action is shown.
If I set the Theme normally, I can't set the action bar like :

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
if (toolbar != null) {
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

Because you have no right to set the action bar if one is already set.

I simply would like to get the back arrow on my Fragments navigation like :

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

I can't figure out how to do that :/

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

```
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_back);
```

Comment: Thx but nop, The thing is that neither the toolbar nor actionbar are shown

Comment: 1)"Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar." 2)extend ActionBarActivity.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: What I use is Theme.AppCompat.Light and <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>.

Answer (score 0):

Provide a Parent Activity in the Manifest.

See http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to set this attribute in your style.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

Then in your Activity:

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
         Toolbar mActionBarToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
         if (mActionBarToolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but that's exactly what I'm doing (and exaclty what all internet and documentation saying) but if I do that, neither the actionbar, neither the toolbar are shown when I call setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Comment: @ThomasLeduc Are you sure that (mActionBarToolbar != null) ?

Comment: Hum, no actually, it's seems too easy but I'll try. You're maybe right :)